# What does the 3rd symbol on this sword label mean?

Tags: character-identification

I have an century+ old sword which has this label:

[image]

A Chinese friend at work said she understood 光雲一刀 = "Light cloud [something] sword" but she couldn't figure out the third character, some kind of classifier, she thought maybe.

Can someone help me with that 3rd character please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks as if characters 1,2 and last (4 or 5?) are left-right reflections of 光，雲，刀

Comment: @user6065 Thanks for pointing that out, you're right, I made a mistake editing the picture (which was upside down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my initial guess, the 3rd character is 刻 (u+523b)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=刻](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%88%BB)

the seal script in the picture is slightly deviated from standard one.

anyway, i guess your sword is made by 光雲堂, a japanese carving knife manufacturer; maybe you can ask them directly :)

http://kouundou.com/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much! So it seems to say "Light cloud engraved sword", you've made my day!